# latitude and longitude get shorten when I try to open them from an Intent and open wrong location in kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, google-maps

I have an app that makes the user insert the location that he wishes and open that location through intent by his lat and lang, I have got a funny bug where all the saved locations open the same place, so I debugged the code and I figured out that I get the Lat and lang from the database correctly, but when I try to parse it into the Uri it gets shortened to only 8 digits.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

SO the Lat for example is 30.071769159909497, it gets shortened to 30.071769 and open a wrong location
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNMYT.jpg

Here is my code

```
    val strUri =
        "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:${place.placeLocationLat},${place.placeLocationLang} (${place.placeName})"
    binding.place = place

    binding.placeLocation.setOnClickListener {
        showMap(Uri.parse(strUri))
    }


    @SuppressLint("QueryPermissionsNeeded")
fun showMap(geoLocation: Uri) {
    var intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
         data = geoLocation
    }
    packageManager?.resolveActivity(intent, 0)

    if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager!!) != null) {
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

I can't figure out why it gets shortened and how I can solve this.

Comment: The 30.071769159909497 is not in your code. Assign it to a variable that you use. Only then we can follow your code.

Comment: if you check this image(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNMYT.jpg), you can see I got the value from lat and long, my issue is that when they are read they are shortened

Comment: What Place class are you using? If it’s your own, please show its code.

Comment: Your code makes no sense if those variable values are not clearly visible in your code. You say a * b = 6 but nowhere there is a = 12 and b = 0.5.

Comment: fyi, this truncation is probably meaningless as it corresponds to a few centimeters http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Decimal_degrees

Comment: Yes I am using a Place data class on my own, it has the variables that I put in the database, and retrieve them, my issue is mainly it gets shortened, I don't get the entire number inside the function

Comment: check the image I have inserted here when I debug @blackapps (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNMYT.jpg)

Comment: That image tells us nothing. Better follow my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you got incorrect location due to typo in code

```
    var lat : Double = place.placeLocationLat!!.toDouble()
    var lang : Double = place.placeLocationLat!!.toDouble()
```

While second line should be

```
    var lng : Double = place.placeLocationLong!!.toDouble()
```

Update:

```
    val lat = 30.071769159909497
    val strUri =
"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:${lat}"
    println(strUri)
```

prints 'http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:30.071769159909497', no truncation

You should check type of your variable.
In code you converting result to Double, why you skip this conversion in string substitution?

Comment: well, i am not using any of these variables, I am using this
val strUri =
        "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:${place.placeLocationLat},${place.placeLocationLang} (${place.placeName})"

while I get tow different values, my issue is that they get shortened